# amcharts export as Zip file

Tags: zip, amcharts4

I want to export amchart chart as a zip file contains a jpg image and an Excel file
I can't find out how to get image object to put in a zip file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The files generated by the export API are data URIs. You need to extract the base64-encoded data from the URI (everything after `"base64,"` in the URI) in order for the JSZip library to add its contents correctly:

```
Promise.all([
  chart.exporting.getExcel(),
  chart.exporting.getImage('png')
]).then(function(exportedItems) {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  zip.file("data.xlsx", exportedItems[0].split("base64,")[1], {base64: true});
  zip.file("chart.png", exportedItems[1].split("base64,")[1], {base64: true});
  zip.generateAsync({type: "blob"}).then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "chart.zip");
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/5114404b7fde6d76739e821b5f8d20ef)